# Unable to Pass the Listobjects in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle

I would like to pass the list of objects to the other activities via Intent, Below are the code I have tried currently

```
public List<Reportgetter> reportlist;

Here reportlist has some values.

Intent graph= new Intent(showdetails.this,Graph.class);

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putParcelable("list", (Parcelable) reportlist);
                graph.putExtras(bundle);

                startActivity(graph);



**Graph Class**
I am receiving like this,
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
        if(extras!=null)
        {

            reportlist = extras.getParcelable("list");
        }
```

But I m getting some Exception. Please help me out regarding this.

Regards
priya

Comment: Could you provide the exception you are receiving? 'Some exception' is rather vague and doesn't provide others a hint of the problem.

Comment: @user1993392 does Reportgetter class implements Parcelable?

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
Intent graph = new Intent(showdetails.this,Graph.class);
graph.putParcelableArrayListExtra("list", reportlist);
startActivity(graph);
```

in Grpah Activity,

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
reportList = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("list");
```

for this to work, your Reportgetter class must implement `Parcelable`

Answer (score 0):

welcome to StackOverflow. Please post us the exception details, so we can help you.

Since you are working with Parcelable objects, my guess is your exception is `android.os.BadParcelableException`.

This is rooted in your class implementation of `Reportgetter`. Please follow the instructions here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html.